# Nonfactors mvcgrid paging server side problems

Tags: c#, paging, nonfactors-mvc-grid

Sorry for my bad English .I've just started using NonFactors.Grid.Mvc6 -Version 7.2.0 server side pagination.
Here is my code in index.cshtml

```
 .Pageable(pager =>
 {
     pager.PageSizes = new Dictionary<Int32, String> { { 10, "10" }, { 20, "20" }, { 50, "50" }, { 100, "100" } };
     pager.ShowPageSizes = true;
     pager.PagesToDisplay = Model.TotalPages;
     pager.CurrentPage = Model.Page;
     pager.RowsPerPage = Model.PageSize;
     pager.TotalRows = Model.TotalItems;
 })
 .Sortable()
```

Here is my paging model:

```
public class PagingModel<T>
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int TotalItems { get; set; }
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }

    public int TotalPages => (int)Math.Ceiling((double)TotalItems / PageSize);
}
```

I put some code in this [Post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av5su.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av5su.png): [Nonfactors mvcgrid paging problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68112668/nonfactors-mvcgrid-paging-problems) to _Grid.cshtml:

```
 @if (Model.Pager != null)
 {
     Model.Pager.TotalRows = Model.Pager.PagesToDisplay * Model.Pager.RowsPerPage;

     @await Html.PartialAsync(Model.Pager.PartialViewName, Model.Pager)
 }
```

And this is my result: [image]

I want to show only 3 page. When i go to page 3, other page 4, 5, 6 is display in pager like this [image]

I will be grateful for any help you can provide. the documentation is pretty poor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your .Pageable method, set the number pages to display to 3 instead of total. TotalRows and TotalItems keep reflecting the actual total. The reason for this is that you should both work with the number of pages that actually exist in your grid (TotalRows and TotalItems) as well as with the number thereof you want to display (PagesToDisplay). Note that TotalRows is not about visual rows, but about rows of data like in a database, which kind of means number of items (in the data, not in the visualization thereof).

```
.Pageable(pager =>
{
    pager.PageSizes = new Dictionary<Int32, String> { { 10, "10" }, { 20, "20" }, { 50, "50" }, { 100, "100" } };
    pager.ShowPageSizes = true;
    pager.PagesToDisplay = 3; // Only affects the display of page numbers in the UI
    pager.CurrentPage = Model.Page;
    pager.RowsPerPage = Model.PageSize;
    pager.TotalRows = Model.TotalItems; // Set this to the actual total number of items in your dataset
})
.Sortable()
```

In your _Grid.cshtml file, you need to add the forward and backward buttons. Something like this:

```
@if (Model.Pager != null)
{
    <div class="grid-pagination">
        <!-- Previous Button -->
        @if (Model.Pager.CurrentPage > 1)
        {
            <a href="@Url.Action("YourAction", new { page = Model.Pager.CurrentPage - 1 })" class="btn-previous">Previous</a>
        }

        <!-- Pagination Numbers (Keep your existing code here) -->
        @await Html.PartialAsync(Model.Pager.PartialViewName, Model.Pager)

        <!-- Next Button -->
        @if (Model.Pager.CurrentPage < Model.Pager.TotalPages)
        {
            <a href="@Url.Action("YourAction", new { page = Model.Pager.CurrentPage + 1 })" class="btn-next">Next</a>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I already try your code. and i got some problem. Your code only show only first page so i add line Model.Pager.TotalRows = Model.Pager.PagesToDisplay * Model.Pager.RowsPerPage; into it. But value of Model.Pager.TotalPages is 3 looklike pager.PagesToDisplay = 3; i set in .Pageable method so if i was in page 3 next button is disappear. Help me please

Comment: You are mixing up the logic that is about the actual amount of pages, and the visualization thereof. A fundamental attempt in patterns like the model-view-controller (mvc) is to clarify the distinction between 'what is' (model), 'what is shown' (view), and 'how this connection is organized' (controller). This is an extreme simplification of only one perspective on mvc, but maybe it clarifies your issue. Your grid, including TotalRows and RowsPerPage is about 'what is' and your PagesToDisplay is about 'what is shown'. I updated the answer to clarify

Comment: I've just solve my problem. Thank you so much.